# mercadopago foreach de productos con php

Tags: php

estoy tratando de colocar lo de mi carrito a una variable para que mi foreach lea la lista del carrito, cabe destacar que si lo integro de un elemento a un elemento funciona bien la integracion de esta pasarela de pago mercadopago

Hola buenas, estoy tratando de colocar lo de mi carrito a una variable para que mi foreach lea la lista del carrito, cabe destacar que si lo integro de un elemento a un elemento funciona bien la integracion de esta pasarela de pago mercadopago

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('TEST-4458050914010150-090922-b5d0fc53c2b851fd9f0d8777919d5f10-187981268');
// Crea un objeto de preferencia
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
$NumItem=0;
$arrayItems = array();
// Crea un ítem en la preferencia
foreach($_SESSION["producto_".$_GET["agregar"]] as $indice=>$producto){
$nombre_de_variable="item"."$NumItem";
  $nombre_de_variable = new MercadoPago\Item();

$nombre_de_variable->id = $producto['id_producto'];
$nombre_de_variable->title = $producto['producto_titulo'];
$nombre_de_variable->quantity = $producto['producto_cantidad'];
$nombre_de_variable->unit_price = $producto['producto_precio'];

$arrayItems[]=$nombre_de_variable;
$NumItem++;
}
$preference->items = $arrayItems;
$preference->back_urls=array(
    "success"=>"http://localhost/ecommerce/captura.php",
    "failure"=>"http://localhost/ecommerce/fallo.php"


);                               
$preference->auto_return="approved";
$preference->binary_mode=true;
$preference->save();

?>
<div class="checkout-btn">


</div>


  ?>
```

esto es Para que el boton de pago de mercadopago

```
  <script>
  const mp = new MercadoPago('TEST-ca471ee1-93e0-416f-9fb5-09533dfeedff', {
    locale: 'es-AR'
  });

  mp.checkout({
    preference: {
      id: '<?php echo $preference->id; ?>'
    },
    render: {
      container: '.checkout-btn',
      label: 'Pagar con mercado pago',
    }
  });
</script>
```

asi es como agrego al carro de compras,ademas setea con 0 cuando no hay ningun producto en el carrito

```
        if(isset($_GET["agregar"])){
      
        $conectar=Conectar::conexion();
      
        $id_producto=$_GET["agregar"];
      
        $sql="select * from productos where id_producto=?";
      
        $resultado=$conectar->prepare($sql);
      
        $resultado->bindValue(1,$id_producto);
      
          if(!$resultado->execute()){
              
              echo "<h1 style='color:red'>Falla en la consulta</h1>";
         
          } else {
              
               if($resultado->rowCount()>0){
                   
                   while($reg=$resultado->fetch()){
                    $_SESSION['CARRITO']=$_SESSION["producto_".$_GET["agregar"]];
                        print_r($_SESSION["producto_".$_GET["agregar"]]);
                       if($reg["producto_cantidad"]!=$_SESSION["producto_".$_GET["agregar"]]){
                           
                          $_SESSION["producto_".$_GET["agregar"]] +=1;
      
                           header("Location:checkout.php"); 
                           
                       }else {
                          
                           header("Location:checkout.php?cantidad=".$reg['producto_cantidad']."&producto_titulo=".$reg['producto_titulo']."");
                       }
                   }
                   
               } else {
                   
                    echo "<h1 style='color:red'>No existen registros asociados</h1>";
               }
          }
      
       
  }
```

`  el error es que el get agregar no encuentra la variable y el otro que en el foreach muestra como null

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el problema o error? Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: ya, pude editar la pregunta

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_SESSION);` y qué muestra un `var_dump($_GET);`? Debes verificar tus datos, lo que hay en ellos y cómo están estructurados.

Comment: $_GET["agregar"] esa es, justo la que no encuentra}

Comment: Depura lo que hay en `$_GET` como he sugerido en el anterior comentario.

Comment: array(0) { } asi me muestra el vardump get                   y el var dump sesion  array(6) { ["CARRITO"]=> int(5) ["producto_1"]=> int(3) ["producto_2"]=> int(0) ["producto_"]=> NULL ["item_total"]=> float(92.97) ["item_cantidad"]=> int(3) }

Comment: vez me sale un null, esto es en session carrito array(6) { ["CARRITO"]=> int(0) ["producto_1"]=> int(2) ["producto_2"]=> int(1) ["producto_"]=> NULL ["item_total"]=> int(123) ["item_cantidad"]=> int(3) }

Comment: Pues como puedes ver, no hay ninguna clave `agregar` en el GET.

Comment: pues como agrego esa clave en el get?

Comment: Pues donde se genera el `$_GET` (formulario o lo que sea) debes poner un elemento (por lo general un botón de tipo submit) con `name="agregar"`, así, cuando el formulario se envíe, en el `$_GET` irá una clave `agregar`.

Comment: sabes si en el render iria de esta forma   render: {
      container: '.checkout-btn',
      label: 'Pagar con mercado pago',
      name: '.agregar',
    }

Comment: No uso MercadoPago, por tanto, no sé cómo funciona. ¿No estás usando un formulario o algo así? ¿Dónde agregas `producto_1`, `producto_2`, etc?

Comment: Por otra parte, la forma correcta de hacerlo no parece ser verificando el `$_GET` del botón, sino de otras propiedades. Ver [este ejemplo](https://github.com/mercadopago/checkout-payment-sample/blob/master/server/php/server.php). Otra cosa rara que veo es que usas código de PHP en el cliente, deberías usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. En el enlace al repositorio que te di más arriba hay un archivo llamado `index.js` que muestra un ejemplo con la API Fetch. Es mejor así, teniendo separado cliente y servidor.